# Собрать значения или имена в массив PHP

Tags: php, массивы, form

Здравствуйте дорогие знатоки PHP, подскажите, столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть форма отправки данных, у неё скрытые input, этим скрытым inpit'aм (можно в name, можно в value) положено имя картинки, вот мне надо собрать их в массив (php), заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input name='img[]' value='name1' />
<input name='img[]' value='name2' />
<input name='img[]' value='name3' />
```

После отправки на сервер имена придут в виде массива.

Comment: Название картинок в массив img помещать? И как обработчик написать, чтобы их собрать

Comment: @Kirill в value, потом смотрите в $_REQUEST['img']